# Add arrow to 3D pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to add an arrow (cf red arrows below) in a 3D plot (or 2D plot should be similar) in pgfplots ?

The arrow has not to be specifically aligned with the label but could be placed closer to the axis.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where `xticklabel cs` comes in handy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
            after end axis/.code={
                \draw [-stealth, thick, red] (xticklabel cs:0.2) -- (xticklabel cs:0.8);
                \draw [-stealth, thick, red] (yticklabel cs:0.2) -- (yticklabel cs:0.8);
                \draw [-stealth, thick, red] (zticklabel cs:0.2) -- (zticklabel cs:0.8);                
            }
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf] {cos(deg(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You got the point! This takes care of the label and is really easy to use...